# Error al validar xml y xsd

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-schema

estoy intentando validar este documento pero me sale el siguiente error :   4:19    schema.xsd  s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'colegio' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: sequence.

En esta web https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator

Este es el codigo: 
**XML**

```
<colegio xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ejercicio3XSD.xsd"> 
    <alumnos>
        <alumno dni="12345678A">
            <nombre>Rosalind</nombre>
            <apellidos>Barker</apellidos>
            <expediente>NX-0001-R</expediente>
            <email>RosalindLBarker@superrito.com</email>
            <foto>foto.jpg</foto>
            <curso>01</curso>
            <modulos>
                <modulo>
                    <nota>6</nota>
                </modulo>
            </modulos>
            <comentario>Bien</comentario>
        </alumno>
        <alumno dni="12345678B">
            <nombre>Colton</nombre>
            <apellidos>Bishop</apellidos>
            <expediente>NX-0002-R</expediente>
            <email>ColtonBBishop@gustr.com </email>
            <foto>foto.jpg</foto>
            <curso>02</curso>
            <modulos>
                <modulo>
                    <nota>7</nota>
                </modulo>
            </modulos>
            <comentario>Bien</comentario>
        </alumno>
    </alumnos>
</colegio>
```

**XSD**

```
<xs:element name="colegio">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:element name="alumnos">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:element name="alumno" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="nombre">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="20"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="apellidos">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="30"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="expediente">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="email">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
                                        <xs:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+|"/> 
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="foto" type="imageType"/>
                            <xs:element name="curso" type="integer"/>
                            <xs:element name="modulos">
                                <complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="modulo" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="10"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                                <xs:element name="nota" maxOccurs="1">
                                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                                                    </xs:restriction>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:complexType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </complexType>
                            </xs:element>
                            <xs:element name="comentario">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:maxInclusive value="50"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>
                        </xs:sequence>
                        <xs:attribute name="dni">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{8}[A-Z]"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:attribute>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

No logro dar con la solucion, he intentado quitar el "colegio" y dejar solo el alumnos y nuevamente me da el mismo error como si se repitiera mucho o algo asi... y no entiendo a que se refiere realmente.

Comment: He resuelto este error , quitando la secuencia en el XSD pero ahora obtengo el siguiente :

s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_colegio' is invalid. Element 'element' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often.